# 'numpy.float64' object is not callable while typing an algebraic equation

Tags: numpy, math, typeerror, exp

I am calculating the value of a variable F, below is my code:

```
F_c=(1+(h_nb*T_gl/q_g)(1- 2.718281**(-((b_o*q_g)/(rho_l*deltah*0.0003)))))**(-1)
```

I have attached an image of the actual equation as well. Can anyone tell me why I would get "'numpy.float64' object is not callable" error on this?

[Actual form of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XWXu.jpg)

Comment: *...`/q_g)(1-` ...* Looks like you are missing an operator between those parentheses. Maybe `*`?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks, cannot believe it was something so trivial!